# Running my program leads to java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.augmentString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lscala/collection/immutable/StringOps;

Tags: java, scala, open-source, dependencies

I am trying to run an open-source program called LinkedIn Norbert (https://github.com/linkedin/norbert) in Scala 2.8.1.  I have added all the jar files so the program compiles, but when I try to run class  com.linkedin.norbert.javacompat.network.RunNorbertSetup in examples/src/main/java, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.augmentString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lscala/collection/immutable/StringOps;
    at com.linkedin.norbert.jmx.JMX$.name(JMX.scala:59)
    at com.linkedin.norbert.cluster.ClusterClient$$anon$1.<init>(ClusterClient.scala:56)
    at com.linkedin.norbert.cluster.ClusterClient$class.$init$(ClusterClient.scala:55)
    at com.linkedin.norbert.cluster.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClusterClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClusterClient.scala:22)
    at com.linkedin.norbert.cluster.ClusterClient$.apply(ClusterClient.scala:33)
    at com.linkedin.norbert.javacompat.cluster.ZooKeeperClusterClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClusterClient.scala:23)
    at com.linkedin.norbert.javacompat.cluster.ZooKeeperClusterClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClusterClient.scala:21)
    at com.linkedin.norbert.javacompat.network.RunNorbertSetup.configCluster(RunNorbertSetup.java:115)
    at com.linkedin.norbert.javacompat.network.RunNorbertSetup.main(RunNorbertSetup.java:21)
```

What would I need to do to get past this error?  I've looked at other Stack Overflow and forum threads, and these have not helped.

FYI: I built the program with SBT.

Thanks so much,
Rebecca

Comment: Basically means an older version of the class is lurking on your classpath. This often happens when one of your dependencies overrides another and includes an older version of the class that doesn't have this method yet. In such a case reordering the dependencies will help (newest version on top). But hard to say for sure, if that's the cause, since don't know your dependency structure.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  Turns out there were Scala libraries from multiple versions in the classpath and I just changed them all to the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to put the relevant class in the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Run a "clean" instead of build. Remove all the build and bin folders from the project directory too.