# unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-slick_2.10;0.6.0.1: not found

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, slick, play-slick

I am getting unresolved dependencies errors when trying to use slick or play-slick with Play Framework 2.2.2, sbt 0.13.0 and Scala 2.10.3 on Mac OS X Mavericks.

```
[info] Updating {file:/Users/michaelrichardson/Documents/Play/glasgowEffect/}glasgoweffect...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#slick_2.10;2.0.0 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#slick_2.10;2.0.0
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/slick_2.10/2.0.0/slick_2.10-2.0.0.pom
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-slick_2.10;0.6.0.1 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#play-slick_2.10;0.6.0.1
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-slick_2.10/0.6.0.1/play-slick_2.10-0.6.0.1.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#slick_2.10;2.0.0: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play-slick_2.10;0.6.0.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#slick_2.10;2.0.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-slick_2.10;0.6.0.1: not found
[error] Total time: 7 s, completed Apr 27, 2014 2:58:48 PM
```

I have tried clearing my ivy cache, running `play clean` and adding different resolvers but nothing has worked.

This is the build.sbt file:

```
name := "Test"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.0.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "0.6.0.1"
)     

play.Project.playScalaSettings
```

**UPDATE: Looked into resolvers**

[play21-osm] $ show resolvers
[info] List(Typesafe Releases Repository: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/, Typesafe Releases: http://typesafe.artifactoryonline.com/typesafe, pk11 repo: http://pk11-scratch.googlecode.com/svn/trunk)
[play21-osm] $ show externalResolvers
[info] ArrayBuffer(FileRepository(local,FileConfiguration(true,None),Patterns(ivyPatterns=List(${ivy.home}/local/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/artifact.[ext]), artifactPatterns=List(${ivy.home}/local/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/artifact.[ext]), isMavenCompatible=false)), Maven2 Local: file:/Users/mr/.m2/repository, public: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/, Typesafe Releases Repository: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/, Typesafe Releases: http://typesafe.artifactoryonline.com/typesafe, pk11 repo: http://pk11-scratch.googlecode.com/svn/trunk)

Answer (score 2):

Quit Play Console, and make sure your `build.sbt` looks like this:

```
name := "Test"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.0.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "0.6.0.1"
)

play.Project.playScalaSettings
```

Delete `$PLAY_HOME/repository/cache/com.typesafe.slick` and `$PLAY_HOME/repository/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-slick_2.10`. You may want to delete complete cache directory if you like to.

Run Play console again and execute `update` followed by `compile`.

Comment: I deleted the complete cache directory. Now when I run Play I get the error: `Error during sbt execution: No repositories defined.` I tried using brew to uninstall and reinstall play and sbt. Didn't fix anything

Comment: And if you go to your project's directory and look in `project/plugins.sbt` do you have repository defined there? Is it a new project or are you trying to build something existing?
Edit: One more thing, can you run play console and execute `show resolvers` and `show externalResolvers` ?

Comment: The project/plugins.sbt file is the standard file for a new play installation. I can't get into the play console. It gives the error `Error during sbt execution: No repositories defined.` and quits only giving that line. I have tried reinstalling sbt with brew, macports and manually and it gives the same error each time. I get the same error when I type sbt at the command line. If I create a new play installation the problem is the same.

Comment: Could these errors be due to me running the following command suggested by another thread? `rm ~/.ivy2/cache/* -R` **<- I don't recommend running this**

Comment: I don't think the command you mentioned does any harm (except the stuff will be re-downloaded from the internet which takes time). Do you have any special repositories defined in a `~/.sbt/repositories`. And again what's the content of `project/plugins.sbt` ? Just to be sure, you launch your play console, by going to the folder where you have your app, and running `play` there, right?

Comment: One more thing (cannot edit a comment), do you have repositories defined in `$PLAY_HOME/framework/sbt/play.boot.properties` and `$PLAY_HOME/framework/sbt/sbt.boot.properties` under a section [repositories] ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51601/discussion-between-lpiepiora-and-michael-richardson)

Comment: ~/.sbt/repositories is empty. play.boot.properties contents ------ [scala]
  version: ${sbt.scala.version}

[app]
  org: com.typesafe.play
  name: console
  version: 2.2.2
  class: play.console.Console
  cross-versioned: binary

[repositories]
  local
  maven-local
  typesafe-ivy-releases: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/, [organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  maven-central

[boot]
  directory: ${play.home}/sbt/boot

[ivy]
  ivy-home: ${sbt.ivy.home-${play.home}/../repository}
-------

Comment: sbt.boot.properties ---- 
  org: ${sbt.organization-org.scala-sbt}
  name: sbt
  version: ${sbt.version-read(sbt.version)[0.13.0]}
  class: ${sbt.main.class-sbt.xMain}
  components: xsbti,extra
  cross-versioned: ${sbt.cross.versioned-false}

[repositories]
  local
  maven-local
  typesafe-ivy-releases: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/, [organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext], bootOnly
  maven-central

[boot]
  directory: ${play.home}/sbt/boot ----- continues below

Comment: [ivy]
  ivy-home: ${sbt.ivy.home-${play.home}/../repository}
  checksums: ${sbt.checksums-sha1,md5}
  override-build-repos: ${sbt.override.build.repos-false}
  repository-config: ${sbt.repository.config-${sbt.global.base-${user.home}/.sbt}/repositories} -----

Comment: plugins.sbt ------ // Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.2") -----

Comment: It is only when typing play in a play project folder that I get the line - `Error during sbt execution: No repositories defined`. Otherwise, I get -        _
[play logo - removed for length] 

play 2.2.2 built with Scala 2.10.3 (running Java 1.6.0_65), http://www.playframework.com

This is not a play application!

Use `play new` to create a new Play application in the current directory,
or go to an existing application and launch the development console using `play`.

You can also browse the complete documentation at http://www.playframework.com.

Comment: Typing `sbt` in the terminal also gives `Error during sbt execution: No repositories defined`

Comment: Fixed the `Error during sbt execution: No repositories defined` issue with the following commands:  cd ~  >  brew uninstall sbt  >  brew uninstall play  >  mv .sbt .sbtold  >  mv .ivy2 .ivy2old  >  brew install sbt  >  brew install play  >  sbt  >  play

Comment: Having fixed the `Error during sbt execution: No repositories defined` I have added the output of the `show resolvers` and `show externalResolvers` as an UPDATE to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Your slick dependency has the wrong group name. It should be `com.typesafe.slick` instead of `com.typesafe.play`:

```
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.0.0"
```

Comment: Thanks but it still gives the error. 

[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.slick#slick_2.10;2.0.0: not found

Comment: @MichaelRichardson This is strange. It should work fine with the correct gorup (on my machine, it does). Do you have a proxy or special resolvers ?

Comment: I am pretty sure that I don't have a proxy or special resolvers. I think that Play, sbt or ivy may have become corrupted and that this is the source of my problem. I used brew to install play and sbt. I used brew to uninstall and reinstall play and sbt but this hasn't fixed it. I deleted the entire cache of play as suggested by lpiepiora and now I get the error `Error during sbt execution: No repositories defined.` when I run the play command.

Answer (score 0):

Very hard to tell if this really was what fixed the problem but it is now working for me.

```
cd ~
brew uninstall sbt
brew uninstall play
mv .sbt .sbtold
mv .ivy2 .ivy2old
brew install sbt
brew install play
sbt
play 

sbt clean
```

I think that my sbt or ivy repositories had become corrupted and this resulted in them being rebuilt.

Comment: I wonder if they became corrupted because there was a lock on one of the files so sbt was unable to read/change it