# Play slick sbt installation error

Tags: playframework, slick

I am running into the following error when trying to install play-slick.
Am running scala 2.11.7 and play 2.4.3
Does anyone know what could be wrong?

```
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/myself/Personal/myapp_play/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/myself/Personal/myapp_play/project/}myapp_play-build...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-slick;1.1.1 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#play-slick;1.1.1
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/play-slick/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/play-slick/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/myself/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.play/play-slick/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/typesafe/play/play-slick_2.10_0.13/1.1.1/play-slick-1.1.1.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-slick_2.10_0.13/1.1.1/play-slick-1.1.1.pom
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-slick-evolutions;1.1.1 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#play-slick-evolutions;1.1.1
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/play-slick-evolutions/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/play-slick-evolutions/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/myself/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.play/play-slick-evolutions/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== jcenter: tried
[warn]   https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/typesafe/play/play-slick-evolutions_2.10_0.13/1.1.1/play-slick-evolutions-1.1.1.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-slick-evolutions_2.10_0.13/1.1.1/play-slick-evolutions-1.1.1.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play-slick;1.1.1: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play-slick-evolutions;1.1.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.typesafe.play:play-slick:1.1.1 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn]      com.typesafe.play:play-slick-evolutions:1.1.1 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.typesafe.play:play-slick:1.1.1 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13) (/Users/myself/Personal/myapp_play/project/plugins.sbt#L17-18)
[warn]        +- default:myapp_play-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn]      com.typesafe.play:play-slick-evolutions:1.1.1 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13) (/Users/myself/Personal/myapp_play/project/plugins.sbt#L18-19)
[warn]        +- default:myapp_play-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-slick;1.1.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-slick-evolutions;1.1.1: not found
```

Comment: Got answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324322/unresolved-dependency-com-typesafe-playplay-slick-2-100-6-0-1-not-found and here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436069/adding-play-json-library-to-sbt